# Is there is any way to use ON DELETE CASCADE feature in adhoc basis using query when ON DELETE RESTRICT is defined?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've created foreign key as `ON DELETE RESTRICT` but sometimes I need to delete child records along with deletion of the parent record. I can't use "ON DELETE CASCADE" because I need that restriction more often. So is there any way to change the behavior of the foreign key in runtime using any keyword or something in the query like below?

```
delete * from table1 where ID='3' CASCADE CHILD;
```

or

```
delete * from table1 where ID='3' SET foreign_key_behavior= 'ON DELETE CASCADE';
```

Comment: You can delete from multiple table at once without using foreign key cascades.. i believe the MySQL syntax is something like DELETE table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id WHERE id = 3.. if that does not work remove the star syntax.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no syntax for forcing an ad hoc cascading delete if you didn't define the foreign key constraint with the ON DELETE CASCADE option.

Doing the DELETE against both tables in a join doesn't work in MySQL, despite the suggestion from @RaymondNijland in the comments.

Demo using MySQL 5.6:

```
mysql> create table foo ( id serial primary key );
mysql> create table bar (foo_id bigint unsigned not null, 
  foreign key (foo_id) references foo(id));
mysql> insert into foo values (1);
mysql> insert into bar values (1);
mysql> delete foo.*, bar.* from foo join bar on foo.id=bar.foo_id where foo.id=1;

ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
fails (`test`.`bar`, CONSTRAINT `bar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES
`foo` (`id`))
```

You'll have to execute a separate delete for each child table, then a delete for the parent table.